# How to locate php notices in a huge project?

Tags: php, notice

I'am allways developing php stuff with error reporting and notices actived. But now i have to refactor a huge project and its produces a lot of php notice messages. This drives me nuts.

Is there an easy way to discover all the lines which will produce such a message in a single run? Maybe a cli tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [the PHPLint project](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/) for which there is an [online demo](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/phplint-on-line.html). You can also [download it](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/download.html).

Comment: "php -l the_file" will not find any notice messages. This just checks for syntax errors. So i'll give phplint a try.

Comment: @DerKlops Thanks for letting me know about `php -l`. I have removed it from my answer as it is obviously now irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own [error_handler()](http://php.net/set-error-handler), that catches the notices (and so on), and write them to a file. After that you can just parse the file and extract (e.g.) every line, that contains the keywords `NOTICE`.

Sadly this is more a "try-and-error", because it catches only notices, that occurs, if the corresponding code is executed.